# Use entityManager to save into two tables with FK in one of the tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I have to insert into a table the ID of a first persisted enity using EntityManager.

My Entity have an ID generated like this

```
    @Id
@Column(name = "PUSH_ID", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "dbSequence", sequenceName = "VVV_PUSH_S", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dbSequence")
public Integer getIdentifier() {
    return identifier;
}
```

I then persist this entity to generate the ID

```
        this.getEntityManager().persist(pushEntity);
        this.getEntityManager().flush();
```

The I pass on the pushEntity.getIdentifier() to an sql statement to insert into the second table like this

```
 selectQueryToInsert.addJoin(PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE, SQLJoinOperator.LEFT_JOIN, PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE + "." + SOURCE_ID_COLUMN + "=" + sourceTableName + "." + DEFAULT_ID_COLUMN + " AND " + PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE + "." + PUSH_ID_COLUMN + "=" +   String.valueOf(pushEntity.getIdentifier));
 selectQueryToInsert.addListValuesRestriction(sourceTableName, DEFAULT_ID_COLUMN, SQLOperator.IN, sourceList);
 selectQueryToInsert.addValueRestriction(PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE, PUSH_ID_COLUMN, SQLOperator.NULL, null);
 selectQueryToInsert.addSelectColumn(DEFAULT_ID_COLUMN);
 String insertQuery = INSERT_SOURCE_QUERY + stringBuilder.toString(selectQueryToInsert); 
 this.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(insertQuery).executeUpdate();
```

Here comes the trick, in the second table "PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE" I have an FK on the ID of the Push and since the entityManager didn't commit the transaction the PUSH_ID does not exist yet in the database and the second insert fails with

```
integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found
```

Is there a different way to do this. Tkx

Comment: errm, why not flush() it first?!

Comment: I do a this.getEntityManager().flush(); before getting the ID that I pass into the preparedStatement

Comment: the log says ? it states all SQL issued, so things can be debugged relatively easily

Comment: I explained already that the issu is that the entityManager does not commit even with flush() so for DB when the statement is executed the push_id PK does not exist yet in the table. It's not a matter of debug I need a suggestion of a different way to do it, if it exist. tkx

Comment: The entity manager will not commit with flush ... it flushes ... to the datastore. So then, in principle, you can use the same connection and push further updates. Depends on the transaction isolation level you have set for that connection with your JPA provider of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating a new entity for my PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE instead of using a preparedStatement

and setting a @Embeddable class holding the parent key of the push entity like this

```
@Embeddable
public class PushEntityPK implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5599662020926504220L;

private Integer push_id;

private String entity_id;

//Default Constructor
public PushEntityPK(){

}

public PushEntityPK(Integer push_id, String entity_id){
    this.push_id = push_id;
    this.entity_id = entity_id;
}
```

and annotated the source table entity with @Idclass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PUSH_SOURCE_TABLE")
@IdClass(PushEntityPK.class)
public class PushSourceEntity implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5162782386822573902L;

public PushSourceEntity(PushEntityPK pushEntityPK){
   this.push_id = pushEntityPK.getPush_id();
   this.entity_id = pushEntityPK.getSource_name();
}

@Id
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "push_id", column =   @Column(name = "PUSH_ID"))})
private Integer push_id;

@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "entity_id", column = @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID"))})
private String entity_id;
```